# How to write Rspec test case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I am beginner to Rails `Rspec` and not getting how to write testing for below code. I have `scope` in my `Trip` model as shown below

```
scope :pending_end_trips, -> {
    joins(:booking).
    where(state: :active).
    where(owners_end_at: nil).
    where("bookings.end_at < ? ", 1.hour.ago)
  }
```

**Here is my code:**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Trip, type: :model do
  fixtures :all

  let(:user_1) { users(:user_1) }
  let(:user_2) { users(:user_2) }
  let(:contact_1) { contacts(:contact_1).tap{ |c| c.update_columns(user_id: user_1.id) } }
  let(:contact_2) { contacts(:contact_2).tap{ |c| c.update_columns(user_id: user_2.id) } }
  let(:rider) { riders(:rider_1).tap{ |r| r.update_columns(user_id: user_1.id) } }
  let(:owner) { owners(:owner_1).tap{ |o| o.update_columns(user_id: user_2.id) } }
  let(:motorcycle) { motorcycles(:motorcycle_basic_1).tap{ |m| m.update_columns(owner_id: owner.id) } }
  let(:booking) { bookings(:booking_1).tap{ |b| b.update_columns(motorcycle_id: motorcycle.id, owner_id: owner.id, rider_id: rider.id) } }
  let(:request) { requests(:request_1).tap{ |r| r.update_columns(booking_id: booking.id, motorcycle_id: motorcycle.id) } }
  let(:trip) { trips(:trip_1).tap{ |t| t.update_columns(booking_id: booking.id) } }

  context 'scopes' do
    describe 'pending_end_trips' do
      it 'returns trips which are supposed to end in past 1 hour' do
        trip.update_columns(owners_end_at: nil, state: :active)
        expect(described_class.pending_end_trips).to include trip

        trip.update_columns(owners_end_at: nil, state: :complete)
        expect(described_class.pending_end_trips).not_to include trip

        trip.update_columns(owners_end_at: nil, state: :canceled)
        expect(described_class.pending_end_trips).not_to include trip

        trip.update_columns(owners_end_at: nil, state: :deleted)
        expect(described_class.pending_end_trips).not_to include trip

        trip.update_columns(owners_end_at: nil, state: :pending)
        expect(described_class.pending_end_trips).not_to include trip
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Getting the below error:**

[image]

Comment: You have two more conditions besides the state of a trip, check if changing those values makes your queries include `trip`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't fit the conditions because you don't specify `end_at` for booking

```
let(:booking) { bookings(:booking_1).tap{ |b| b.update_columns(end_at: Time.now - 2.hours, motorcycle_id: motorcycle.id, owner_id: owner.id, rider_id: rider.id) } }
```